# Get Commit Hash of Previous Commit that changed a specific File

Tags: git

To get the previous commit key / hash **of another commit key** there is `COMMITKEY^1`.

But in context of a file (e.g. `Example.java`), is there a way to get the previous commit to another that changed `Example.java` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log -1 --pretty=%h <base commit> -- Example.java` will print the the latest commit that has touched the Example.java file starting from <base commit> (thanks to [ElpieKay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay)). The base commit can be i.e. HEAD~1 if you want to start looking from the previously made commit.

Comment: It outputs a list of latest commits with descriptions, not just the commit key of the previous commit to an arbitrary commit key.

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas replace `--oneline` with `-1 --pretty=%H`. `%h` for short format. The output is the hash of the commit that modifies the file for the last time.

Comment: @ElpieKay: That helps, thanks. :) But it's still a list of commits.

Comment: That's the format I was looking for. :) But still I was not asking for the latest commit, but for the previous commit of any commit hash.

Comment: Previous to what?

Comment: Previous to a commit that is not the current commit. Imagine the file has a commit history of A -> B -> C: So for C I want to get B, and for B I want to get A. This is actually what ``COMMITKEY^1`` does, but not in the context of a file. I think it's possible with your solution, but would probably need to checkout always. Not sure, maybe the <revision_range> parameter could help?

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Command :

```
git log --name-status
```

which will show output as :

```
commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Author: xyzauthor <xyzauthor@email.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 24 20:16:07 2017 +0530

    changes done in folder name

M       filename.java
```

Now Just use `git checkout` with commitID as below :

```
git checkout xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```